# New iTunes gives error: iTunes cannot verify the identity of the server "safebrowsing.clients.google.com"

Tags: itunes, certificate

I can browse to https://safebrowsing.clients.google.com/ but it just redirects me to Google's home page.

[image]

iTunes 12.5.5.5, Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this same error on multiple occasions in iTunes 12.5.5.5 on Windows 10 when I tried to sync my iPhone.

I just upgraded to iTunes 12.6, and I no longer see that error.

Answer (score -2):

This is an issue with iTunes 12.5.5 that needs fixing by Apple.